# How to batch export multiple e-mails in Outlook 2010 into multiple .mht?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client

Currently using Windows 7 Pro x64 with Outlook 2010.  Is there a way to batch export multiple e-mails in Outlook 2010 into multiple .mht files for archival purposes?

Bonus points for an automated script job to conduct this export on a monthly basis.

Comment: If you don't mind using a commercial product then check out [MessageExport™ Add-in](http://www.outlookextractor.com/2013/02/convert-outlook-email-text.html)

Comment: Is .mht format a strict requirement? Why not just use more common and flexible .eml format?

Comment: Or why not export as .PST file, so you have a message archive that you can load and have the entire mailbox with subfolders ready?

Comment: @thims - No, it's not a requirement, but it's a file format that can be natively opened in Windows without additional installs.  I don't see an option to save to .eml format in Outlook 2010, please show me.